# NSDate distantFuture

Tags: nsdate, nsrunloop, operation

I have a problem about [NSDate distantFuture],I use it like this:

```
while (_connection != nil)
    {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSData distantFuture]];
    }
```

I get a warning "Class method '+distantFuture' not found(return type defaults to 'id')".I run the code, an Error:-[NSConcreteData timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x80d18e0

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteData timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x80d18e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1e63022 0x1606cd6 0x1e64cbd 0x1dc9ed0 0x1dc9cb2 0x10af3e1 0x72181 0x11300ad 0x18a9330 0x18aa439 0x95707b24 0x957096fe)
terminate called throwing an exception.
I use [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2],the error is the same.
Could someone help me? thx a lot.

Answer (score 5):

NSData is not NSDate.  try: [NSDate distantFuture] instead.